# How to hide path to real index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have web project where index file is on deep folder.

Lets say my project index is on `localhost/xxx/a/b/c/index.php`, but I want to hide `/a/b/c` path become `localhost/index.php`.

How to code `.htaccess` and where I should put it?

Thank you.

Comment: just make **c** the web root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in public_html/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
#if the request is not for and existent file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#and the request is not for and existent directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#then rewrite it to /a/b/c/request
RewriteRule ^(?:xxx/)?(.*)$ /xxx/a/b/c/$1 [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect

```
example.com/file.php
```

to

```
example.com/a/b/c/file.php
```

Comment: How if i don't have public_html folder?

Comment: You can use it in your root folder.

Comment: smarter to just make c the web root

Comment: i try to put it on my localhost/xxx/.htaccess but it doesnt work?
any other clue?

Comment: it works thankyou,.
my apologies, but when i access it without index.php, it doesn't work,.
how to make it works like usual,.(localhost/xxx/==localhost/xxx/index.php)
thank you..

Comment: See the another edit, I  replaced + with a * star ,it matches zero or more characters in request.

Comment: If my answer has solved your problem ,you can accept it so that it does not show up in unanswered ones. otherwise let me know how I can improve it.